# How do i concatenate and style a list of strings in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working on a WPF/XAML app using MVVM and have a collection of strings as a property on my viewmodel. I would like to concatenate the strings for display within a textblock or similar control. The strings should be concatenated using the text " AND " and the concatenation text should be styled using a bold font weight. The output would look something like this:

cat **AND** dog **AND** mouse **AND** rabbit

What is the best way to achieve my end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't bind to the read-only [TextBlock.Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property, I would suggest to create a derived TextBlock with a `TextList` property:

```
public class TextListBlock : TextBlock
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextList", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(TextListBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((TextListBlock)o).TextListChanged((IEnumerable<string>)e.NewValue)));

    public IEnumerable<string> TextList
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(TextListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextListProperty, value); }
    }

    private void TextListChanged(IEnumerable<string> textList)
    {
        bool addSeparator = false;
        foreach (string text in textList)
        {
            if (addSeparator)
            {
                Inlines.Add(new Run(" AND ") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
            }

            Inlines.Add(new Run(text));
            addSeparator = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This solution is simpler and provides better re-usability than the one that I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a ViewModel for each item in the collection (an animal in the case of my example). In doing this, I added a property called IsNotLast that would help me to determine when I should display the "AND" text to go between the items. Additionally, I made use of the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://andu-goes-west.blogspot.com/2009/05/wpf-boolean-to-visibility-converter.html) so that the visibility property in my XAML would be set appropriately.

Below is the example XAML using an ItemsControl and a DataTemplate.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding AnimalName}"
    />
            <TextBlock
        Text=" AND "
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Visibility="{Binding IsNotLast, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```